Can I utilise time series properties of the data, WITHOUT creating lags?
I am working on a project where the train and test sets are given to me. The data (stock returns) is time series by nature, but the point is that I cannot create lags because that would mean discarding the top k observations because they would not be able to have the lags.
Why is that a problem for me? Because I will get judged by the MSE on the testset, which is calculated by a predefined script which has the true values (which I do not have access to). So that means I cannot drop any values from the test dataset. I would have gladly implemented a LSTM or AR(I)MA on the data, but since that would mean that for prediction I would have to create lags in the testset too, I am stuck with Random Forest and XGBoost.
Is there any way I could utilise time series properties of the data, WITHOUT CREATING LAGS, or does there exist any Deep Learning methodologies that will allow me to do that (I do not know of any)?
Thanks, I appreciate your kind input.

If you cannot afford to drop even one value for your analysis, then you have far too few data to succeed anyway.

Perhaps a State-Space model could be valuable, where you can estimate what the lagged expectations may have been and then propagate these latent states forward in time? Also do you have access to information from other series that could help you to estimate these dynamics, or perhaps to other regressors? These can of course help you to build a more robust forecasting model

I’m still not clear about why you can’t create lags. Could you please clarify?

@Dave I have a test set in which I need to generate predictions for EACH observation. So if I created, say, a lag of 10 for my model, then I would not be able to predict anything for the first 10 observations of my test set

@NicholasClark that sounds interesting. Do you mean the stuff like Factor models and Kalman Filters etc.?

@whuber that's not it. i have around 100k rows for my training (which I will split into train and val) and 85k for the test. The point is I would be more than happy to drop the top k observations in the train and val, but as I explained to Dave, I need to generate predictions for EACH observation in my test set.
Consider a Python script to find the MSE (which I don't have access to) that has the correct answers and is generating the MSE. If my predictions vector size is less than the test_target vector size (85k) then the script will error out.

This sounds like an XY problem to me.  I suspect the real issue might concern how to select subsets of time series data analysis for testing and cross-validation, rather than any problem with using lags--that is, with the data analysis itself.  But what you're doing and what the actual problem are both remain unclear to me, because I cannot determine whether you are describing a statistical problem or just the failure of your code to work.

I still don’t understand why you can’t create the lags. Do you train on data in the far past before your test set? Time series forecasting inherently use the past to make predictions about the future. Do you not have access to the values from the past? Why not?

@Dave the point is I simply haven't been given the timestamps of the dataset. I have not created the dataset, I have been given it, and it does not have timestamps as a column.

@whuber suppose you create lags of upto 10. Then in the first 10 observations, will you not have NaNs in place of where you were supposed to have the lag values since the backwards data simply isn't available?

That's always the case in any time series analysis.  I still fail to understand how or why that's a problem with your analysis.

Why aren’t you using the previous ten measurements when you make those new predictions?

If your data is 'time-series by nature' then next value depends on the previous. When you say 'I don't want to use lags', you are going directly against this. The problem with not having previous history for the very first measurement is not a problem of time series model. You will simply need to do special treatment for the first few points, and then use time-series. For example, you could impute those values from some reasonable distribution

@Cryo I would upvote that if you posted it verbatim as an answer.

@Cryo your comment really makes sense, would you post that as an answer, probably append how to sample reasonably from the distribution (random? mean?)

@Dave and insipidintegrator, thank you. DOne

If your data is 'time-series by nature' then next value depends on the previous. When you say 'I don't want to use lags', you are going directly against this. The problem with not having previous history for the very first measurement is not a problem of time series model. You will simply need to do special treatment for the first few points, and then use time-series.
The treatment you do really depends on the thing you are trying to model. Best case scenario you have some background knowledge. You say you are trying to forecast stock returns. I guess this is a floating-point number. If it can be positive and negative you could model it as normally distributed, if it is strictly positive, Log-Normal distribution might do. If it is strictly non-negative, you may need to look towards Gamma distribution, or some sort of zero-inflated Log-Normal (mixture of Log-Normal and a uniform distribution in the vicinity of zero).
More formally, if we are thinking about something like ARMA model, with dependent variable $y_t$ (at time $t$), vector of independent variables $\mathbf{x}_t$, and normally distributed noise $e_t\sim Normal\left(0,1\right)$, then the model could be:
$$
\begin{align}
y_t&=\theta_1\cdot y_{t-1}+\theta_2\cdot y_{t-2}+\dots +\theta_p\cdot y_{t-p}+\boldsymbol{\beta}.\mathbf{x}_t+\nu_0\cdot e_t+\nu_1\cdot e_{t-1}+\dots,\quad t\ge p \\
y_t&\sim Normal\left(\mu_b,\sigma_b^2\right),\quad t<p
\end{align}
$$
Where you fit baseline $\mu_b$ and $\sigma_b^2$ along with the rest of the parameters. For LSTM and other machine learning techniques you can sort of do something similar for $\mu_b,\,\sigma^2_b$. You can sample from z-distribution, generate new batches of data for each of these samples, and then treat $\mu_b,\,\sigma^2_b$ as parameters that need to be optimized as part of the neural network params. I believe this is essentially reparametrization trick. Not sure whether you are set on LSTM so will not go deeper here.
Of cause the $t<p$ distribution does not need to be normal. This is when the expert knowledge really helps. If this number is so important that you model it, surely someone can tell you what is 'typical' for this number. If not, you can simply provide some reasonable degrees of freedom: mean, scale (variance), perhaps skewness. You then fit all of these parameters to your data. The fact that you don't have, for example, $y_{t<0}$ will not necessarily be a problem, since the data that you do have will be more or less probable for different $\mu_b,\,\sigma^2_b$ and this is enough to fit these parameters.
